# Reloading ChartJs Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, chart.js

I have a chart and before creating a new chart in the same canvas, I call the `myccc.destroy();` and it works well.

However, if I create a image of chart and after that If I create a new chart, image persist. Obviously, I need to remove image of chart as well as chart itself before redrawing the chart.

I tried this;

```
$("#dialog_chart_img").remove();
$(".dialog_chart_img_div").append('<img id="dialog_chart_img" style="width: 655px; height: 580px; margin-top: 40px;" />');

if (myccc != undefined || myccc != null) {
     myccc.destroy();
    }

var ctx = document.getElementById('dialog_chart');

      var myccc = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'horizontalBar',
          data: {
            labels: array_zaman,
            datasets: [{
              label: "Yumurta",
              data: array_adet,
            }]
          },
          options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            responsive: true,
            // maintainAspectRatio: true,
            legend: {
              display: false
            },
            animation: {
              duration: 1,
              onComplete: function(animation) {
                var chartInstance = this.chart,
                  ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
                ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "charter");
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';

                this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                  var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                  meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                    var data = dataset.data[index];
                    ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y);
                  });
                });
                document.querySelector('#dialog_chart').remove();
                document.querySelector('#dialog_chart_img').setAttribute('src', this.toBase64Image());
              }
            }
          }
        });
```

Html:

```
<div class="dialog_chart_img_div">
    <img id="dialog_chart_img" style="width: 655px; height: 580px; margin-top: 40px;" /> <br> <br>
    <canvas id="dialog_chart" style="visibility:hidden;"></canvas>
</div>
```

How can I reload the image after creating a new chart?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem but can't you just redraw the chart by doing myccc.update() ?

Comment: It didn't work. I just need to remove image of chart, redraw the chart and make new image of new chart to insert to same canvas.